# How to lock a single cell using a macro, but without protecting sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to run a macro which will populate certain cells automatically then lock the information in the cell at the end of the macro so other users cannot edit once populated.

Is there a way to protect/lock a single cell using a macro and without protecting the sheet?

Thank you

Comment: Not that I know of.  I think you need to protect sheet and unlock all other cells.

Comment: Hi Philip, Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to use the suggestion I had in the comment to make the spreadsheet feel unprotected but not for that single cell of interest.

```
' set cell range you want to be editable.  I used a random range here
Worksheets("yoursheet").Range("A1:G100").Locked = True
' suppose you want B2 locked
Worksheets("yoursheet").Cells(2,2).Locked = True
' protect the sheet
Worksheets("yoursheet").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
```